# How can i fix problem "Duplicate class androidx" in Android Studio Flamingo?

Tags: android-studio, duplicates

after updating android studio to flamingo version and upgrading gradle version to 8.0 i have problem to build code

I am pasting the error that is displayed when building the application:

```
Duplicate class androidx.collection.LruCache found in modules collection-1.1.0 (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NavUtils found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentBuilder found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentReader found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.content.IntentCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.content.pm.ActivityInfoCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.database.DatabaseUtilsCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.util.DebugUtils found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.util.LogWriter found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.util.TimeUtils found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MotionEventCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.VelocityTrackerCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewConfigurationCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewGroupCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat$AccessibilityStateChangeListenerCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.EdgeEffectCompat found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter$CursorFilterClient found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$CursorToStringConverter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$ViewBinder found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState$1 found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState$1 found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$1 found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$BackStackEntry found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$OnBackStackChangedListener found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState$1 found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState$1 found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$1 found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2 found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.SuperNotCalledException found in modules fragment-1.3.6-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6) and jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$3 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$4 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$Status found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$BroadcastRecord found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$ReceiverRecord found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and localbroadcastmanager-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip$PageListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$2 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$ItemInfo found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$LayoutParams found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$PagerObserver found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState$1 found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SimpleOnPageChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-v4-r7 (com.google.android:support-v4:r7) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
```

my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'pl.com.xx'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation ('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    
}
implementation 'com.luckycatlabs:SunriseSunsetCalculator:1.2'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'

   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation    "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"
    implementation 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

agp_version = '8.0.2'
gradle version: 8.0
JDK: 17.0

I tried to remove dependencies, but it didn't work